# if else statement in data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of 6 column and 4.5 millions rows. I would like to write a logical check if in the fifth column there are values with zeroes, to put 1 in the sixth column. Could you explain me how to construct an algorithm to do this? In the fifth column I found that I have cells with zero value. I want to perform if in the fifth column I have zero values to put 1 in sixth column and if not to put 0? I must use data.table package. I try with this 
name of the data[,6] = ifelse(name of the data[,5] == 0, 1, name of the data[,6]).

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and the expected result based on that.  For guidelines, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: When i use read.csv I had no problem. Due to the fact that I use data.table I am unable to use this command df[,6] = ifelse(df[,5] == 0, 1, df[,6])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using`data.table`, we can use `:=`, which would be more efficient (example data from @plafort's post)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.4+
setDT(df)[X5==0, X6:=1]
```

Comment: It works for me. It looks like the syntax is `setDT(df)[<when this is true>, <do this>]`. And by extension, `[<when this>, <do this>, <by this factor>]`

Comment: Hi guys it works. Thank you again for the support I really appreciate your help. I would like to thank you Akrun for help.

Comment: @plafort, that's a very nice way of explaining the general idea behind!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R way:

```
df[,6][df[,5] == 0] <- 1
```

In many cases, you can avoid having to write explicit `if` statements. The conditional is implied in the subset. Reading it out would say, "In the sixth column of the data frame, assign the value of 1 to all values adjacent to column five." Someone more familiar with assigning column values in `data.table` can easily apply it to your case.

**Data**

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(replicate(6, sample(0:5, 3)))
df[2,5] <- 0
df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  1  3  0  1  1
2  3  0  4  1  0  5
3  4  2  5  4  5  3

df[,6][df[,5] == 0] <- 1

df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  1  3  0  1  1
2  3  0  4  1  0  1
3  4  2  5  4  5  3
```

Comment: I can't apply it when i use data.table.

Comment: Use akrun's suggestion. @akrun add an answer if you would like.